# Changing all text color in Frame

Tags: c#, .net, wpf, frame, visualtreehelper

I want to change all my text in my application (wpf) programmatically, it works form my Grid on my mainwindow (BaseGrid) with:

```
private void setTextColor()
    {

       Color myColor = Brushes.Red;

            for (int i = 0; i < VisualTreeHelper.GetChildrenCount(BaseGrid); i++)
            {
                Visual childVisual = (Visual)VisualTreeHelper.GetChild(BaseGrid, i);

                    childVisual.Dispatcher.BeginInvoke(new Action(() =>
                        {
                            childVisual.SetValue(Label.ForegroundProperty, myColor);
                        }));                
            }
    }
```

but when i change the "BaseGrid" for "myFrame", text in myFrame is not being changed, I load pages in them. I want to be able to change the color in the Page in myFrame the same way.

Need some help here.

Comment: One question. If you put `Foreground = Red` in your `myFrame` via XAML, does it works?

Comment: Nope, guess i need to target the loaded page in the frame somehow

Comment: I was trying to replicate here and got the same error. Your code looks Ok. If you want ALL Controls to be Red, you'll only need to set the foreground as Red, since the controls inherits properties (bubble)

Comment: So replace label.foregroundproperty to foreground? And keep myFrame as visualchild?

Comment: hate to burst your bubble but, setting Foreground property is not being inherited by my frame